# Change color of a part of text inside a <p> tag according to user selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome; as a part of it there is a text highlighting capability.

I've managed to highlight a complete `<p></p>` tag (or any other tag) but I can't figure out how to highlight a part inside a tag. (user will not select an entire tag)

I found that I should use `<span>` inside the `<p>` tag but I can't figure out a way to do it.

1. How do I identify the part that the user selected?
2. How do I highlight the selected part (eg change the back color)?

A detailed explanation would be really helpful and highly appreciated, since I'm new to extension development.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is split the text into 3 parts:

1- the text before the selected text.

2- the selected text.

3- the text after the selected text.

Then I clear the element's innerHTML (or another method), add the 'before' text, add a span with their text as its text (which has a style that can be highlighted), and the 'after' text.

---

To find out what they selected, you can use ranges (selectionStart & selectionEnd)
e.g.,

```
var html = elem.innerHTML;
var before = html.slice(0, elem.selectionStart);
var selected = html.slice(elem.selectionStart, html.selectionEnd);
var after = html.substring(html.selectionEnd);
```

This method isn't perfect, but it's a good starter to learn with.

Comment: thanks it really helps . so if i want to extend it to many tags (assume that user select text from many tags , there may be links , < src > tags also ) how can i extend this. can i use the same code ??

And how will this code trigger. I mean how can i detect that (for just for < p > tags we can user  eventListeners ). Usually  we use 'onclick' or 'onmouseup' like events. Should i use some event listeners for this ? if so how can i use them ?

Comment: For changing the highlight color, you can just use CSS [read more here](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)